# Advanced Filtering of Associated Entity Collection in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

If I have an associated entity which is a collection, what options do you have when fetching?

e.g. Lets say I have a `$view` entity with this definition inside it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion", mappedBy="entity")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"timeMod" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $versions;

public function getVersions() {
    return $this->versions;
}
```

And I want to get the all the versions associated with the entity like this:

```
$view->getVersions();
```

This will return a collection. Great. But is it possible to take that collection and filter it by criteria, e.g. newer than a certain date? Or order it by some (other) criteria?

Or at this point are you just expected to do a query on the repository:

```
$versions = $em->getRepository("GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion")->findBy(array(
    array(
        'viewId', $view->getId(),
        'timeMod', time()-3600
    )
    // order by
    array('timeMod', 'DESC')
));
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a surprisingly unknown feature in recent versions of Doctrine, which makes these sort of queries much easier.

It doesn't seem to have a name, but you can read about it in the Doctrine docs at [9.8 Filtering Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

> Collections have a filtering API that allows to slice parts of data from a collection. If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to large collections.

In your case you could write a method like this on your `View` entity.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class View {
  // ...

  public function getVersionsNewerThan(\DateTime $time) {
    $newerCriteria = Criteria::create()
      ->where(Criteria::expr()->gt("timeMod", $time));

    return $this->getVersions()->matching($newerCriteria);
  }
}
```

This will do one of two things:

1. If the collection is hydrated, it will use PHP to filter the existing collection.
2. If the collection is not hydrated, it will fetch a partial collection from the database using SQL constraints.

Which is really great, because hooking up repository methods to your views is usually messy and prone to break.

I also like @igor-pantovic's answer, although I've seen the method cause some funny bugs.

Comment: This is an interesting feature for certain use cases. But doesn't this make PHP do the filtering? So if the database will have to fetch possibly hundreds (or thousands) of records, what are the performance considerations?

Comment: No, that is precisely the point of it. If the collection hasn't already been hydrated, it will pre-filter the collection in SQL. I've updated the answer with a snippet from the Doctrine docs that explains it.

Comment: Very interesting. At this point though, what's the difference between using a criteria filter, versus just doing a advanced query with Doctrine's Query Builder? What are the use cases when you would use the criteria over the regular advanced query?

Comment: Can you override the default `getVersions()` function using this way ? To apply a kind of global filter

Answer (score 1):

I would personally avoid using order by on annotation directly. Yes, you are supposed to do a query, just as you would if you were using raw SQL without Doctrine at all.

However, I wouldn't do it at that point but even before. In your specific case I would create an `ViewRepository` class:

```
class ViewRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findWithVersionsNewerThan($id, \DateTime $time)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('view')
            ->addSelect('version')
            ->join('view.versions', 'version')
            ->where('view.id = :id')
            ->andWhere('version.timeMod > :time')
            ->setParameter('time', $time)
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$yourDateTime = // Calculate it here ... ;
$view = $em->getRepository("GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion")->findWithVersionsNewerThan($yourDateTime);

$versions = $view->getVersions(); // Will only contain versions newer than datetime provided
```

I'm writing code from the top of my head here directly so sorry if some syntax or method naming error sneaked in.

Comment: Thanks. I could add something like that to my existing ViewRepository, I just wasn't sure what was recommended (y). If I need to do pagination, is it possible with this createQueryBuilder syntax? Or only with raw DQL queries like this example: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Comment: Also, what are the reasons to avoid using orderby in the ORM annotation for the associated entity? Just general performance requirements? If every time I request it I will want it ordered in this way though, is there any reason NOT to have that?

Comment: Ugh, you haven't mentioned pagination before. If there was any pagination involved I'd advise you to just query these things separately: Fetch View in one query and fetch versions you need in another.

Comment: :D start simple, and then expand. I've got limit and offset working with basic ->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($limit) but I am still exploring the other pagination options... I can ask it as a different question. NP.

Comment: That's the point, I think It's a lot simpler, cleaner and, later, easier to tune and adjust two queries than a complicated single one.

Comment: Yes I may have confused you. In my case, I am only fetching the version actually. I already have the view and I just want the versions associated with it. So my examples both just query the versions, no joins in my queries. (Although what doctrine does behind the scenes is voodoo to me)

Comment: Limits and maximum results work the same way with query builders and DQL. Query builders are generally (always?) converted to DQL anyway. It's really a matter of preference, which you use. Pagination also works with Doctrine's collection filtering feature.