# Is it possible to define custom SQL query inside an entity in Symfony3

Tags: sql, symfony

looking for good practices here =)

Basically, I got one Entity, which is linked to Elems with a ManyToOne Relationship.

Lets say I want to select only some Elems from my Entity.

I can do

```
class Entity { 
    /* some vars here */ 
    public function getSpecificElems(){
        forEach($this->elems as $elem){
            /* do stuff here */
            if($someCondition){ $result[]=$elem;}
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

But that could imply large data fetching when there are many elems linked to my Entity. The other way would be

```
$em->getRepository("AppBundle:Repository")->getSpecificElems($entity);
```

Where `getSpecificElems` executes a DQL query.

I have got a problem here : the first solution is more intuitive to me because it is OOP. The second one is faster to execute, but seems bad to me.

Is there a way to mix both of 1) and 2) in order to get `$entity->getSpecificElems()` to return the list I want executing the good SQL query ?

Cheers,

Comment: 2) is the best solution

Comment: putting this into the repository is absolutely the way to go to for filtering or paging of related entities, and btw totaly oop as well

Comment: @johnSmith : why is this OOP while you use the EntityRepository to get Entity properties instead the Entity itself ?

Comment: youre free to filter inside the entity, this answer states arrayCollection does filter  results on sql level http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689043/advanced-filtering-of-associated-entity-collection-in-symfony

Comment: The "correct" ORM approach is to use a custom query to load the desired Elems when you query for the Entity.  In fact, an argument can be made that lazy load should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an Entity you can filter an ArrayCollection using Criteria class:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

But this solution is not optimized if you have many data stored in db because Doctrine fetch all the data and then the filter is applied. The best approach is to filter the result using Dql queries.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Seems to do the filter on SQL level according to @johnSmith's comment. 
Thanks =)